# Map CUSIP to CIK

Tags: data, data-mining, edgar

I'm trying to analyse 13F filings and those provide CUSIPs and names. I hoped the names would be sufficient to find the relevant Edgar filings but the names are often imprecise (e.g., "ABBOTT LABS" instead of "ABBOTT LABORATORIES" so Edgar search fails).

If I had a way to reliably map CUSIPs to CIKs that would solve my problem - but "official" way of https://www.sec.gov/edgar/NYU/cik.coleft.c is a mapping from names to CIKs and again the names in 13F don't match the names in that file.

So my question is - what's the best free way to get from CUSIPs to CIKs? Or alternatively from CUSIPs to the same names as Edgar uses?

Comment: This really depends on which databases you have access to. If you can access WRDS or Bloomberg, it's straight forward to create a mapping table. Compustat has 9-digit (header) CUSIPs and CIKs, for example.

Comment: I don't have access to commercial databases. This is a hobby project.

Answer (score 3):

This repo gives a pretty straightforward process for building a CUSIP to CIK mapping CSV, it also includes a recent mapping CSV generated by the script.

https://github.com/leoliu0/cik-cusip-mapping